# How do I install plastic window insulation without damaging the trim?

Tags: windows, energy-efficiency, trim

I'm planning to install plastic window wrap on my windows for the winter, but the trim around the windows is nice wood and I don't want to leave a mark on it where the double-sided tape will be.

I've seen cases where a very obvious strip is left behind after removing the double-sided tape, and also where the finish on the trim is damaged when the tape is removed.

Are there ways to prevent damage to the trim, or is it something to worry about when removing the plastic in the spring (e.g. special cleanup procedures)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cleaners like "Goo Gone" seem to work quite well on adhesive residues. I keep some around just for those occasions.

Comment: WD40 also does a great job at removing adhesive residues. Actually, any oil (including cooking oil) works, albeit less effectively.

Answer (score 3):

You could try attaching the adhesive strip to the edge of the window trim - ie: not the face, but the side of it. if any is left after the winter is over, it'll be less noticeable

Answer (score 1):

You can heat the adhesive up with a hair dryer and carefully pull it up and it generally doesn't leave much residue.  Also, only leave it attached as long as you need it.  I've attached mine to the walls before instead of the trim, but some residue is always a risk.

Answer (score 1):

In a rental that was terribly insulated... I've put up painters tape around the frame and put the double-sided tape directly on the painters tape. This was in a place with a lot of humidity.